# Variable substitution when sourcing file

Tags: bash, variables

suppose we are sourcing a file with 1000 variables:
          
          var1=50
          ....
         var1000=100

how can i expand these variables so that if i define an argument matching var1...var1000 as a string,it will display their values? for example:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 source file
 var3=$1 #assume that $1=var1
# [ variable substitution here ]

 if [ -z $var3 ];then
  echo "variable value is: ... " <-i want value of 50 to be printed
 else 
  echo "variable does not exist"
 fi

# (if $1=var1 or $1=var2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your problem ? Compare two strings : `[ "str1" = "str2" ]` ? Use variables : `[ $str1 = $str2 ]` or `[ "$str1" = "$str2" ]` to avoid error if one variable isn't defined ? Use `or` in `test` expression : `[ exp1 -o exp2 ]` so `[ "$1" = "$var1" -o "$1" = "$var2" ]` ?

Comment: 2 variables where just an example. If i have a 1000-variable file, i want to quickly check if my argument matches one of these. I ve done it using grep, however i want to make it more elegant.

Comment: for i in "$@" do if [ -z  $var3 ]; then echo "$number" else echo "variable does not exist" fi or you can do  case $i in "var1")

Comment: this doesn't work. I want to print the value of argument.

Comment: if argument matches one string and this string is defined as a variable in sourced file, then i want to print the value of it.

Comment: In the "if" condition, use $((var3)) instead of $var3. Your issue would be solved and you can pass the variable (that either exists or does not) as an argument to the script.

Comment: I think you want [indirect expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). Something like `echo "${!var3}"`. Try it: `a=hello; b=a; echo "${!b}"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't really understand the question but assume you want to do something like this.
In that you want to check the values in the sourced file.

The below uses bash [indirect expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> The basic form of parameter expansion is `${parameter}`.
>
> [...]
>
> If the first character of *parameter* is an exclamation point (!), it introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of *parameter* as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of *parameter* itself. This is known as `indirect expansion`.

```
#!/bin/bash

source file

var3="$1" #assume that $1=var1

if [[ -n ${!var3} ]];then 
#Check if the variable that has been sent to script has value in sourced file
    echo "variable value is: ${!var3}"
    #If it does echo the value
else
    echo "variable does not have value"
    #if it doesn't then state it has no value
fi
```

#### Usage

Assuming `var1=50` is in file and there is no `var20` in file then below is an example of the usage.

```
$ ./script.sh var1
variable value is: 50
$ ./script.sh var20
variable does not have value
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks for the edit, some pretty silly mistakes there but why did you add `[[]]` when it is not needed?

Comment: It's not that it's not needed, it's just that (in Bash) the `[[ ... ]]` construct is preferred over the old style `[ ... ]` construct. You can rollback if you don't like it `;)`. (though I fixed the quote from the manual, so make sure you don't rollback that part).

Comment: thanks, it works ;) that's exactly what i wanted; marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the `if` condition, use `$((var3))` instead of `$var3`. Your issue would be solved.

Comment: Only if name contained in `var3` is numerical; otherwise, `bash` continues to recursively expand the contents. For example, `foo=bar; bar=baz; $((foo)` expands to 0, not "baz", if there is no variable named `baz`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. But in that case, I hope the if condition can be changed to '$((var3)) -eq 0' for achieving the required. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, the point is that in this case, if the indirection is for variables with numerical values, you can take advantage of the recursive lookup performed by arithmetic expansion. But in general, it is not a substitute for indirect parameter expansion.

Comment: Oh! K. Got it. Thank you Chepner.